# How can I refactor my arrow functions to use an if statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have these arrow functions:

```
handleTest = () => {
        this.setState({ test: {a: true}})
    }
    handleTest1 = () => {
        this.setState({ test1: {a: false}})
    }
```

And I called them like this in a component:

```
this.props.handleTest();

this.props.handleTest1();
```

But I would like something like this:

```
handleTest = (a) => {
    if(a == 'test'){
         this.setState({ a: true })
    }
    else if(a == 'test1'){
        this.setState({ a: false })
    }
}
```

and call that function like this for instance:

```
this.props.handleTest("test");
```

How can I do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the problem that you're facing ? You already gave a solution ! what seems to be the issue exactly ?

Comment: Yeah your doing it actively

Comment: What about `handleTest = (a) => {
 this.setState({ a: a == 'test' }) }`? It does not keep track of undefined if that is what you also wanted to know.

Comment: No because I want to use state if

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two possibilities in your state logic then you could use ternary statement.

```js
// Your arrow function which is passing through props
handleTest = (condition = undefined) => {
  this.setState({ a: Boolean(condition) });
}

// Calling
const { handleTest } = this.props;

handleTest('test'); // true
handleTest(); // false
```

Comment: `condition` is already a expression. so you could just do `{a: condition}` or `{a: Boolean(condition)}`

Answer (score 0):

```js
handleTest = (a = false) => {
    let temp = a == 'test'
    this.setState({ a: temp })
}
```